# creating NAs for every alternate row for a given column in dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to replace duplicated values across rows in a given column with `NA`s. I am providing here an example of the dataframe and also the desired nature of the column.

```r
# defining the dataframe

df <- structure(
  list(
    condition = c(4, 4, 6, 6, 8, 8),
    main = structure(
      c(2L,
        1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L),
      .Label = c("0", "1"),
      class = "factor"
    ),
    counts = c(8L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 12L, 2L),
    perc = c(
      72.7272727272727,
      27.2727272727273,
      57.1428571428571,
      42.8571428571429,
      85.7142857142857,
      14.2857142857143
    ),
    `0` = c("27.27%", "27.27%", "57.14%",
            "57.14%", "85.71%", "85.71%"),
    `1` = c("72.73%", "72.73%",
            "42.86%", "42.86%", "14.29%", "14.29%"),
    `Chi-squared` = c("2.273",
                      "2.273", "0.143", "0.143", "7.143", "7.143"),
    df = structure(c(1L,
                     1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "1", class = "factor"),
    `p-value` = c("0.132",
                  "0.132", "0.705", "0.705", "0.008", "0.008"),
    significance = c("ns",
                     "ns", "ns", "ns", "**", "**")
  ),
  class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df",
            "tbl", "data.frame"),
  row.names = c(NA, -6L),
  vars = "condition",
  .Names = c(
    "condition",
    "main",
    "counts",
    "perc",
    "0",
    "1",
    "Chi-squared",
    "df",
    "p-value",
    "significance"
  ),
  indices = list(0:1, 2:3, 4:5),
  group_sizes = c(2L,
                  2L, 2L),
  biggest_group_size = 2L,
  labels = structure(
    list(condition = c(4,
                       6, 8)),
    class = "data.frame",
    row.names = c(NA, -3L),
    vars = "condition",
    .Names = "condition"
  )
)

# print the dataframe
print(df)
#>   condition main counts     perc      0      1 Chi-squared df p-value
#> 1         4    1      8 72.72727 27.27% 72.73%       2.273  1   0.132
#> 2         4    0      3 27.27273 27.27% 72.73%       2.273  1   0.132
#> 3         6    0      4 57.14286 57.14% 42.86%       0.143  1   0.705
#> 4         6    1      3 42.85714 57.14% 42.86%       0.143  1   0.705
#> 5         8    0     12 85.71429 85.71% 14.29%       7.143  1   0.008
#> 6         8    1      2 14.28571 85.71% 14.29%       7.143  1   0.008
#>   significance
#> 1           ns
#> 2           ns
#> 3           ns
#> 4           ns
#> 5           **
#> 6           **

# I want the significance column to be
# ns
# NA
# ns
# NA
# **
# NA
```

Created on 2018-03-21 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

In other words, I want every duplicate value of `significance` to be replaced by an `NA`. How can I do this? Will prefer answer with `dplyr`, if possible.

Comment: I'd suggest `df$significance[duplicated(df$condition)] <- NA` but that isn't dplyr

Comment: It's actually `df$significance[duplicated(df$significance)] <- NA`

Comment: @bala83 - not according to the desired result OP posted.

Comment: just a minor comment, it is recommendable not to use names of base R functions (`df`) in your data sample , because it can mess up other people's environments.

Comment: Also, How to select which of the duplicated values will be replaced by NA? @thelatemail 's answer does (to my understanding of it) give a solution which depends on the order of the rows. Is this what you want?

Comment: @Tjebo Thanks for the tip! I used `df` just for this example. It actually doesn't matter which of the duplicated values of `significance` column are converted to `NA`s as long as the unique values are preserved, for reasons unimportant for this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems like a replacement operation:

```
df$significance[duplicated(df$condition)] <- NA
```

If dplyr is necessary, you could wrap it via an `if_else`:

```
df %>%
  mutate(significance=if_else(duplicated(condition), NA_character_, significance))
```